# Subset operator behaving inconsistently

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, set

Working on a project that stores and fetches data in sqlalchemy, I encounter a confusing error in testing a custom filter function. The filter function returns a list of "Move Orders" from the database, and in testing I assert that this list is a subset of the list of all orders:

`assert filtered_orders <= all_orders`

I have three "Stockpoints" (other sqlalchemy table class) that may have MoveOrders associated with them, and running this test in a loop over each, it passes for all except the last "Stockpoint":

```
assert filtered_orders <= all_orders 
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'MoveOrder' and 'MoveOrder'
```

As seen in the error message, on the last pass (last stockpoint), it evaluates the lists to be of type MoveOrder; the type of the lists' **elements**. Some further inspection:

```
print(f"types: {type(filtered_orders)} and {type(all_orders)}")
>types: <class 'list'> and <class 'list'>

assert isinstance(filtered_orders, list)
assert isinstance(all_orders, list)
assert filtered_orders <= all_orders
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'MoveOrder' and 'MoveOrder'
```

As you can see in the last code block, inspecting the variables `filtered_orders` and `all_orders` individually shows that they are of type list and pass individual `isinstance()` asserts... until the line where they are evaluated with the <= operator!
Any idea how this sudden "change of mind" could be occurring?

Comment: `<=` is for sets, not lists.

Comment: It would appear that comparison is not defined for class `MoveOrder`. If you want to evaluate one list of `MoveOrder` objects being a subset of another, you'll need to use sets.

Comment: @FrankYellin: `[1,2] <= [1,2,3]` is valid syntax, but it requires that the objects themselves be comparable.

Comment: If you only want to compare that filter takes just some elements not all of them, you can use `len()` to compare number of elements in those two lists:

`assert len(filtered_orders) <= len(all_orders)`

Comment: @sj95126 thank you, I indeed needed to check them as sets, not as lists: 
assert set(filtered_orders) <= set(all_orders)
I still haven't gotten to why the error message says a variable is MoveOrder Object when isinstance() says it is list object, and why only on the third stockpoint's orders, but at least my tests work now :)

Comment: @sj95126.  You are absolutely right.  The question was about subsets, and I completely spazzed that <= has a meaning, just a different one, for lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's enough details flying around in this question that I thought it would be worth putting up an answer.

The reason why you're having trouble is that `<=` and other comparison operators mean different things between sets and lists. For sets,

```
{1,2} <= {1,2,3}
```

is testing whether set1 is a subset of set2 (in this case, the result is `True`).

However:

```
[1,2] <= [1,2,3]
```

is **not** testing subsets - `<=` isn't defined that way for lists. In the case of lists, what you're actually testing is this:

```
list1[0] <= list2[0] and list1[1] <= list2[1] and ......
```

that is, each element is compared against each other element at the same position. That's why this:

```
[1,2] <= [1,2,3]
```

is `True` but this:

```
[2,1] <= [1,2,3]
```

is `False`.

This explains the error; when you do this:

```
filtered_orders <= all_orders
```

it's comparing a `MoveOrder` object in `filtered_orders` to a `MoveOrder` object in `all_orders`, but class `MoveOrder` does not have the `<=` comparison defined, so the operation fails. As you've tried, checking for subset using sets fixes the issue.

Comment: It might be helpful to add a proposed solution, such as `assert set(filtered_orders) <= set(all_orders)`. This comes with the caveat that you need to make sure equality is defined on the objects in the list.